# If $0 = \left(TH\right)^\perp = \ker T^*$, then $TH = H$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$ with the following property

$$0 = \left(TH\right)^\perp = \ker T^*$$

where $T^*$ is injective, then $TH = H$.

### Discussion

I've been looking at this for a few days now and I don't know why it's true. The only thing I can figure out is that $\left(TH\right)^\perp = 0 \implies TH$ is dense. But the role $T^*$ plays here is perplexing me. Is this true for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces?

Comment: I think this is not true. First, $(TH)^{\perp}=0$ immediately implies $T^*$ is injective. Consider $H=L^2[0, 1]$, for $u\in H$ define $Tu$ to be the function $Tu(x)=\int_0^x u(t)dt$. Now $Tu\in H$ is continuous (although not all continuous functions are $Tu$), these form a dense space in $H$.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this is true.

Consider $$ T :l^2 (\mathbb N) \rightarrow l^2( \mathbb N )$$
$$ (x_n)_ n \mapsto \left (\frac {x_n}{n} \right )_n$$

Then $T$ is compact self adjoint and $ Range \ T \supset c_c(\mathbb N) $ . So in particular $ Range \ T ^ {\perp} =0= Ker \ T^* $ .

But $ T$ is not surjective as there's no preimage of $\left (\frac {1}{n}\right )_n$